# Find the equation of a hyberboloid with given base, narrowest section, and the distance between them

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analytic-geometry, conic-sections

I have one question left in an assignment and I havn't been able to solve it. I know the equaton for a hyperboloid and I know that $a$ and $b$ will be equal to each other. I don't know how to solve for $c$ though. $a = b = 110$ in this problem.

> A cooling tower for a nuclear reactor is to be constructed in the shape of a hyperboloid of one sheet. The diameter at the base is $260$ m and the minimum diameter, $500$ m above the base, is $220$ m. Find an equation for the tower. (Assume the center is at the origin with axis the z-axis and the minimum diameter is at the center.)

Answer (score 1):

It's convenient to put the origin of coordinate system in the center of the narrowest part. Then the equation takes the form 
$$
\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{a^2} = 1 + \frac{z^2}{c^2}
$$
where $a=110$ as you noted. At vertical distance  $z$ from the center, the radius of cross-section is 
$$
R = a\sqrt{1+z^2/c^2}
$$
It remains to plug  $z=500$, equate the radius to $260/2=130$, and solve 
for $c$.